# How to get a scroll bar to reach the maximum in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar

I am using a Vertical Scroll Bar (VScrollBar) object and setting the minimum and maximum values...

```
MyScrollBar.Minimum = 0
MyScrollBar.Maximum = 243
```

but find that however many times I click the down-arrow, the value does not exceed 234. The scroll bar is so short that the actual slider bar is invisible and only the arrows are usable.

How do I set up the scroll-bar so the maximum value is attainable?

I could just add a bit to the maximum value but this seems like a bit of a hack and likely to present difficulties if the scrollbar changes length, which it will do in the fullness of time. I also looked through the properties and couldn't find any likely culprit, or at least not one with a value around 11.

Comment: What is the value of the "SmallChange" property?  That is the amount the value is incremented by when you click the arrows (or use the keyboard arrow keys).

Comment: @tcarvin `SmallChange` is set to 1.

Comment: Well, I got nothing then.  Perhaps set the LargeChange to 1 as well?  Just grasping at straws...

Comment: @tcarvin, no luck, I'm afraid. Thanks for trying, though.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting Maximum to be:

```
Maximum = Max_you_want + LargeChange - 1
```

This works for me.